# python's scipy.stats.ranksums vs. R's wilcox.test

Tags: python, r, scipy

Both python's scipy.stats.ranksums and R's wilcox.test are supposed to calculate two-sided p-values for a Wilcoxon rank sum test. But when I run both functions on the same data, I get p-values that differ by orders of magnitude:

R:

```
> x=c(57.07168,46.95301,31.86423,38.27486,77.89309,76.78879,33.29809,58.61569,18.26473,62.92256,50.46951,19.14473,22.58552,24.14309)
> y=c(8.319966,2.569211,1.306941,8.450002,1.624244,1.887139,1.376355,2.521150,5.940253,1.458392,3.257468,1.574528,2.338976)
> print(wilcox.test(x, y))

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x and y 
W = 182, p-value = 9.971e-08
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Python:

```
>>> x=[57.07168,46.95301,31.86423,38.27486,77.89309,76.78879,33.29809,58.61569,18.26473,62.92256,50.46951,19.14473,22.58552,24.14309]
>>> y=[8.319966,2.569211,1.306941,8.450002,1.624244,1.887139,1.376355,2.521150,5.940253,1.458392,3.257468,1.574528,2.338976]
>>> scipy.stats.ranksums(x, y)
(4.415880433163923, 1.0059968254463979e-05)
```

So R gives me 1e-7 while Python gives me 1e-5.

Where does this difference come from and which one is the 'correct' p-value?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends on the choice of options (exact vs a normal approximation, with or without continuity correction):

R's default:

> By default (if ‘exact’ is not specified), an exact p-value is computed
>   if the samples contain less than 50 finite values and there are no
>   ties.  Otherwise, a normal approximation is used.

Default (as shown above):

```
wilcox.test(x, y)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x and y 
W = 182, p-value = 9.971e-08
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Normal approximation with continuity correction:

```
> wilcox.test(x, y, exact=FALSE, correct=TRUE)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x and y 
W = 182, p-value = 1.125e-05
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Normal approximation without continuity correction:

```
> (w0 <- wilcox.test(x, y, exact=FALSE, correct=FALSE))

    Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x and y 
W = 182, p-value = 1.006e-05
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

For a little more precision:

```
w0$p.value
[1] 1.005997e-05
```

It looks like the other value Python is giving you (4.415880433163923) is the Z-score:

```
2*pnorm(4.415880433163923,lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 1.005997e-05
```

I can appreciate wanting to know what's going on, but I would also point out that there is rarely any practical difference between `p=1e-7` and `p=1e-5` ...

Comment: Yes, Scipy returns the z-score here. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ranksums.html

Comment: I believe there may also be differences when handeling ties, which may have to be handled specifically in scipy.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Do you know if there is any way to force Scipy to calculate an exact p-value and also handle ties? I know there is an alternative function in Scipy called scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu which handles ties and does a continuity correction, but that's still not exact and the docs state that I should have at least 20 samples each for it anyway.

Comment: sorry, I don't do Scipy, so I have no idea ... there is a python-to-R interface ( http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html ) in case that's useful ...

Comment: I am trying to stick with Python for performance reasons, but thanks for the link! It looks like their scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu function will be the thing to use, since it seems to be the only option supporting ties. It's apparently not meant for sample sizes < 20, but I guess this would be the same in R, right?

Comment: If you have very small samples, the normal approximation might not be good and exact or permutation p-values will be more reliable. scipy doesn't have those for mannwhitneyu or equivalent tests. From Ben's first quote, it looks like R is also using the normal approximation in the case of ties.

Comment: The help file for `?wilcox_test` also mentions ... `wilcox_test in package "coin" for exact, asymptotic and Monte Carlo conditional p-values, including in the presence of ties`